# Endnotes starting with a quote: Align

Tags: spacing, footnotes, csquotes, endnotes

In my document, I have an endnote, which starts with a quote. My minimal working example looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%Endnotes:
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

%Left allign endnotes:
\renewcommand\enoteformat{%
  \justify
  \leftskip=1.8em
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\theenmark. \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox}}%
}

\begin{document}

This is the main text\footnote{\begin{displayquote}
This is a nice quote
\end{displayquote}
This is the description of the quote}.
The main text continues.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Now, on the output, there is a vertical space between the number of the endnote and the quote, as can be seen as follows:

[image]

Is there a nice way to remove this space? Of course, I could do it by hand by adding a suitable \vspace{-some measure} before \begin{displayquote}, but it would be nicer if I could delete this space in a more systematic way.